# I can't communication with PCs behind my VPN server

Tags: vpn, l2tp

My scenario is:

- Local net = 192.168.0.0/24
- GW and VPN server = 192.168.0.3
- Reserved IP for VPN clients = 192.168.0.87 to 99

I'm using OpenSWAN + xl2tpd + PPP on Debian "Squeeze" 6.0.5 with kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64.

The connection has been established, but I can't ping any PC behind the VPN server.

"Why Mr. Anderson, why?"

Comment: Did you check your firewall settings? Check the logs to see if you have dropped packets.